# Resize images while uploading to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am Developing an API in PHP and I have to upload images with resize. How can I resize images while uploading to an Amazon S3 bucket?

I have to upload the maximum dimensions of 1920*1080 images

Comment: Instead of trying to resize the images yourself, you could use cloud services like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The 'AWS way' would be to create an s3 event notification for the bucket you are uploading images to, and then have an Lambda function get called each time a new file is put into the bucket - the lambda function would do the resizing and either save the new image to a different location or a different name.

All your PHP app needs to do is 'put' the object in the bucket, and let lambda do the rest - quite certain there are lots of examples around the internet to do this exact thing.

Comment: is AWS support lambda function in PHP?

Comment: Is it possible to connect php aws SDK - lambda? I meant AWS PHP SDK invokes lambda function and then upload to s3. Currently ec2 uploads images to S3 using PHP SDK and then resized by lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You have to resize the images locally with PHP first before uploading them to S3. You can use an already available PHP library for resizing, for example [php-image-resize](https://github.com/gumlet/php-image-resize).

Comment: I think the best library would be imagine https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using image optimization services like Cloudinary which can directly connect to AWS bucket. But this is available in Paid plans only as explained in https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520492-Can-images-be-stored-in-my-own-S3-bucket-

Another way can be to host clone of Imgur; another image optimization service on your own S3. Process explained here: https://hackernoon.com/building-a-highly-scalable-imgur-clone-with-lambda-and-s3-aaf9da422c3e